# Global environment variable are resolving by Jenkins Extended Email notification

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am using Email extension version:2.81. I am facing issues while resolving environment variables.
It was working fine few days ago.

$BUILD_NUMBER

$PROJECT_NAME

above are few variables which I am trying to resolve, but it sends $BUILD_NUMBER and $PROJECT_NAME in email instead of actual values.

Comment: Try this ${BUILD_VERSION} and let me know.

Comment: @mdabdullah, I tried, still no luck, as I said it was working few days ago, and suddenly it is not working, I tried restarting my jenkins as well. No luck

Comment: Can you update the plugin to latest version?

Comment: It looks like we're having the same issue since the last update. Maybe it's a problem with the plugin. I'll share our solution if we find one.

Comment: @PandaTGAttwood I tried with 2.80 as well, it is not working. Also I tried using gmail smtp on my personal machine, it is working fine there with latest version. Do you think it could be issue with outlook? or organization infra ?

Comment: Looking at our Jenkins error logs, it looks like the cause of this issue for us is https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-64556. A recommendation in there is to downgrade to Jenkins 2.273. We've not tried it yet but it looks like some others have had success with that.

Comment: @PandaTGAttwood, I will try downgrading and let you know the result

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue as you @Akash Patil. The issue happened when upgrading from Jenkins 2.273 to 2.274 in earlier, and upgrading to 2.275 did not solve the issue too. Besides, I tested the latest Extended Email Extension plugin (v2.81) with 3 versions of Jenkins and it works fine with v2.273 rather than Jenkins 2.274 & 2.275.

However, I found out in my case, I need to update the `Token Macro Plugin`  to the latest version v2.14, then the Extended Email notification would work properly in Jenkins v2.273, v2.274, v2.275.